# How can I start Nginx with php-fpm based on Ubuntu image using Dockerfile?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, docker, dockerfile

I have `Dockerfile` with a few commands:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get install -y nginx php5 php5-fpm
ADD . /code
```

When I run `docker build .` command I get next error:

```
E: Package 'php5-fpm' has no installation candidate
INFO[0006] The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get install nginx php5 php5-fpm] returned a non-zero code: 100
```

How can I start `Nginx` with `php-fpm` based on `Ubuntu` image?

Comment: running `apt-get update` before `apt-get install [...]` does not solve the problem ?

Comment: Have you considered using the official php image? https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/php/

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, No, I'm in indecision to use official PHP, Nginx or make custom image manually based on Ubuntu. There is also a problem that php and nginx official images based on Debian, not on Ubuntu what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a more [complete example here](https://github.com/dockerfile/nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile) for `NGiNX`:

```
# Install Nginx.
RUN \
  add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y nginx && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && \
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx
```

For `php-fpm`, you have [this example](https://github.com/octohost/php5/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E5267A6C; \
    echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php5-trusty.list; \
    apt-get update ; \
    apt-get -y install php5-fpm php5-mysql php-apc php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-cli php5-gd php5-pgsql php5-sqlite php5-common php-pear curl php5-json php5-redis redis-server memcached php5-memcache ; \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

In both cases, note the usage of:

- `add-apt-repository` in order to add the relevant repos for those packages to install
- `apt-get update`, in order to [downloads the package lists from the repositories and "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/a/222352/5470).